# How to create virtual machine for ARM platform?

Tags: software-installation, virtualization, arm

I have `u-boot.bin`, `kernel.img` and `rootfs.tar` files for arm imx6 board. I want to run a virtual ARM machine in my Ubuntu PC using these ARM compiled images, for debugging.

If possible please provide the link to install and instructions for how to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out
[gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Liryna/10710751)

I am not sure you can test out u-boot with this method but the guide does provide rootfs and kernel testing. Follow the directions for armhf since imx6 is armhf architecture.